# Yielding the year and month from a date with a regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to extract a date in a yyyy-MM format with a regex.

The data I have could be:

```
2019年9月予定 --> Should yield 201909
2020年5月 --> Should yield 202005
2019年8月下旬 --> Should yield 201908
```

The only way I found so far is to extract it in couple of regex:

```
(?<!年)(\d) --> Working but not nice
(?<!月)(\d) --> Not working as also selecting the year
```

Comment: Can you extract year and month separately into two capturing groups and then concatenate them?

Comment: Yes sure, that's fine. How about the month then? How do you ensure only the month is extracted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following (assuming there are no more numbers after the month)

```js
function extractDate(text) {
    const matches = text.match(/\d+/g);
    return matches.join(matches[1].length === 1 ? '0' : '');
}

console.log(extractDate('2019年8月下旬')) //should return 201908

console.log(extractDate('2019年12月下旬')) //should return 201912
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of options. You can do it with a single one with captured groups (which I would choose if possible) or two separate Regexes:

```
^(\d{4})年(\d{1,2})
```

You can also give the groups names so you don't have to use the numbered index.

Or for example:

```
^\d{4}
(\d{1,2})(?=月)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"2019年9月予定".replace(/年(?<month>\d)月.*/, "0$<month>").replace(/年(?<month>\d\d)月.*/, "$<month>")
```

Comment: This returns 20199. The desired output is 201909